# Is it possible to change a DataSnapShot to a Model?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-adapter, datasnap

I am using things like this:

```
int id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId().hashCode();
```

That works perfectly. No I need to get the model from the DataSnapShot. Is that possible? I tried something like this:

```
Note note = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(getAdapterPosition())...
```

But I don't know how to finish this or even if it' possible. Maybe I need a completely different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `onBindViewHolder()` method has as an argument a `ViewHolder` object named `viewHolder`, to solve this, please use the following code:

```
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
Note note = snapshot.toObject(Note.class);
Log.d("TAG", pm.getNodeId());
```

Assuming you have in your model class a fied named `nodeId` and the corresponding getter named `getNodeId()`, the output in your logcat will be, all the ids of your notes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only thing is that I use this lines in `onClick`, so I only use `getAdapterPosition()` instead of `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`. But works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you can convert it. here is example:

```
val yourModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourModelClass::class.java) as YourModelClass
```

that's it :)

---

java style:

```
YourModelClass yourModel = (YourModelClass) getDataSnapshot().getValue(YourModelClass.class)
```